# Single docker image thats being deployed as 2 different services thru kubernetes and helm. Change context path of app

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, kubernetes

We have a single docker image thats being deployed as 2 different services thru kubernetes and helm with names like "ServiceA" and "ServiceB". At the point deploy happens need to set the context path of Tomcat to be something different like /ServiceA and /ServiceB. How can this be done ? is there anything that can be set directly on the yaml ?

ex: Looks like below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "fullname" . }}-bg
  {{- include "labels" . }}

spec:
  replicas: {{ .replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "name" . }}-bg
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  strategy:
    type: Recreate 
    rollingUpdate: null 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "name" . }}-bg
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .image.repository }}:{{ .image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .image.pullPolicy }}
          env:           
            - name: SERVICE_NAME
              value: "ServiceB"
            - name: background.jobs.enabled
              value: "true"
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: {{ include "commmonBaseName" . }}-configmap
            -
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few approaches into setting up the context path of an app.

- From the app itself: This depends on the language/framework/runtime your application uses. For example, if it's a traditional Java web application that runs on Tomcat, it would be served by default from the context path of the name of the  `.war` file you put in the `webapp` directory. Or, if it is a Spring Boot 2.X app, you could set it up with the Spring Boot property `server.servlet.context-path`, which can be also passed via an environment variable, specifically `SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH`. So, to give an example, in the container in your deployment pod spec:

```
env:           
  - name: SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH
    value: "/ServiceB"
```

However, this kind of app-specific settings are most of the times not needed in Kubernetes, since you can handle those concerns on the outer layers.

- Using Ingress objects: If you have an Ingress controller running and properly configured, you can create an `Ingress` that will manage path prefix stripping, and other HTTP Layer7 concerns. This means, you can leave your application itself as-is (like serving from root context `/`) but configure the context path from the Ingress. An example is the following, assuming you use [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service-a-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: service-a.yourdomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /ServiceA/(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: service-a
              servicePort: service-a-port
```

Note the capture group `(.*)` in the `path`, and `$1` in the rewrite target - it will rewrite the request paths like `/ServiceA/something` to `/something` before forwarding the packet to your backend.

See [this page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) to lear more about ingresses.

- You can use an HTTP router software such as [skipper](https://github.com/zalando/skipper) to handle all this HTTP traffic configuration in-cluster.
- If you use a service mesh solution such as [Istio](https://istio.io/), they give you [many ways to manage the traffic](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/) inside the mesh.